# How to get subcategories of a category in magento

Tags: magento

how can I get the all subcategories of a category in magento if there are many nested subcategories?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$subcats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($your_category_id);
foreach ($subcats as $sub) {
    echo $sub->getName();
}
```